# Chrome Extension Message from ContentScript on Event not being listened to

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` fires on an event within a contentScript, background.js/popup.js is unable to receive/respond-to the message. However, when I have `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`fire on the contentScript on execution rather than an event, popup.js is able to respond, but not background.js

**Relevant parts of manifest.js**

```
 "background": {
    "scripts": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*/*"],
    "js": ["lib/jquery.js", "crop.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"
  }],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "camera.png",
    "default_title": "Take a screen shot!",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**Relevant Parts of popup.js that listens to event**

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    initPopup();
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
          console.log(sender.tab ?
                      "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                      "from the extension");
          sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
          return true;
    });
})
```

**Relevant part of popup.js that programmatically injects crop.js (the contentScript)**

```
 function promptCrop() {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'lib/jquery.js'
      })
      chrome.tabs.insertCSS({
        file: 'crop.css'
      })
      chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'crop.js'
      })
    }
```

**Relevant parts of crop.js (contentScript)**

```
    $(overlay)
    .mousedown(function(ev) {
        //irrelevant
    })
    .mousemove(function(ev) {
        //irrelevant
    })
    .mouseup(function(ev) {
        isDragging = false;
        cropPause(ev);
    })

function cropPause(ev) {
    cropSelect.end.x = ev.clientX;
    cropSelect.end.y = ev.clientY;

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log('message was sent');
        alert(response);
    });
}
```

The above *crop.js* does not work. The messages always return undefined. However if `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`is sent outside of the event, anywhere on the script standalone, the eventlistener on popup.js can respond to it.

Comment: When closed, the browserAction popup simply doesn't exist so none of its code runs. BTW  `return true;` is not needed here because you're not invoking sendResponse from an asynchronously executed code.

Comment: @wOxxOm Then I must try to listen to the event from background.js right? However, I can't get 'chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener' to work on background.js. Is this because I am injecting the contenscript from popup.js?

Comment: Using background page script is the correct solution which should work regardless of how the content script was injected. Add the relevant parts of background.js in the question.

Comment: My background.js is actually empty right now. The reason I inject contentScript from popup.js is because I needed to access the domElements of popup.js to attachevents to them.

Comment: Whoops sorry. I meant it is empty except for when I was testing 'chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener' lol. Otherwise the eventlistener on background.js is the same as in popup.js. 

Currently I'm reading into how to properly inject contentScripts via background.js rather than popup.js. I think my solution lies there.